RegEx - String contains specific verbiage
I am new to RegEx, but I am trying to setup a process that sets a designated 'Role' based on an employee's title.
For instance, I have a list of key phrases that point to the user having a role of 'Fleet Manager' if their job title contains 'Logistics Officer'. The problem is that their job titles in the system are prefixed with the country office they're working for - for example 'Kyrgyzstan - Logistics Officer in Kyrgyzstan'.
I need  to be able to match the 'Logistics Officer' part of their title so that the system can then set their role to 'Fleet Manager'.
I've tried using
^.*Fleet, Logistics Officer, Finance and Administration Director, Director of Administration and Finance, Finance and Administration Manager, Finance and Administrative Manager, Transport and Logistics Assistant.*$

This type of work does not typically fall under my umbrella of responsibilities so I apologize for my ignorance.

Is it all like this? Kyrgyzstan - Logistics Officer in Kyrgyzstan?  x - title in x? In that case, you can use a pattern like -\s*(.*)\s+in? or try: \b(Fleet|Logistics Officer|Finance and Administration Director|Director of Administration and Finance|Finance and Administration Manager|Finance and Administrative Manager|Transport and Logistics Assistant)\b

What language are you using? In Python, just use if "Logistics Officer" in job_title:

SO is not a tutoring service, we can't teach you how to write regular expressions.
